# TFS -locked for checkout by in workspace- but the Server was decommissioned

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

TFS- is locked for edit from DEV Server, older server which was decommissioned. I don’t have access to that workspace to unlock if from Visual Studio,so it needs to be overridden from the TFS server.

**Error:**

[image]

**/DISK1/Setup.exe is locked for Check-out by user(name) in workspace DEV Server**

I have tried with **TFS Side Kicks** by using server name, would not find the workspace of above path.

Comment: Have you tried to unlock this file from a TFS admin account?

Answer (score 1):

Talk to your administrator or someone who has the permission of Unlock other user's changes, to use [Lock Command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/lock-command) to removes a lock from this item:

The following example unlocks and makes all files in the src/ Team Foundation version control server folder available for check-out and check-in by other users.

```
c:\projects>tf lock /lock:none src/
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**
You should be able to find the workspace using TFS Side Kicks. I am guessing that one of your other filters are incorrect, e.g. *Owner name* or *Last accessed date(from)*. By deleting the workspace you also delete the check-out lock.

**Option 2**
You can also find the file/directory in Visual Studio Source Control, right-click it, select Find and *Find by Status*. In the resulting dialog press Find and you should see the check-out lock. Right-click on the file(s) and select *Undo...*.

Both operations require that you are part of the administrator group for the Team Project in question.